# Is There any Sandbox for Azure App service for free?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have Azure App Service to work with xamarin froms but i need a Free azure app service for test

Answer (score 2):

there is a free tier of Azure App Service, you can use that for testing.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/